# In App Review(Ratting)play core dialog not showing in live app but when same app(version) internal app testing it is showing?

Tags: android, in-app, google-play-core

I have implemented In app review(In app rating) in Android app it working in via testing internal app testing(Internal app sharing) but it is not working in live app(Production App) does anyone has  any idea ?

Thanks for help in advance!

https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review

Answer (score 0):

As it is explained in the documentation that you linked, Google reserves the right to dictate the 'quota' on how often, or even when, to show or not show the In-App Review Dialog.

> Note: The specific value of the quota is an implementation detail, and it can be changed by Google Play without any notice.  - [Source](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review#quotas)

From my experience, if you're able to confirm that your review flow is valid using Internal Testing, then you're already golden.  Google will decide when to actually show this to your Users, which is not going to be *all* the time.

Moreover, I've noticed in my personal projects that not even I (the sole developer) am able to go into the Play Store page and review my own application when I want!  There's some sort of logic hidden under the hood that Google does not share, and there's no real way around it.  Nevertheless, I can assure you that the review Dialog will come to your Users whenever almighty Google chooses to, as I've seen it working in more than one of my personal + professional apps.

Either way, I hope this at least helps.  Check out [my article in Medium](https://medium.com/proandroiddev/an-inquiry-into-androids-in-app-reviews-3a10083eec1a) on the topic while you're at it too, perhaps it can help further!